# How to use "save as" command in AppleScript with MS Word

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I want to convert MS Word document (docx) to PDF with AppleScript.

I tried the code below with Script Editor.
(MS Word document is opened beforehand.)

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    set outpath to "Documents/test.pdf"
    set activeDoc to active document
    save as activeDoc file name outpath file format format PDF
end tell
```

and failed with the error:

```
The active document doesn't understand "save as" message. 
number -1708 from active document
```

---

### Versions

- macOS Mojave 10.14.4
- Microsoft Word for Mac 16.27 (19071500)
- Script Editor 2.11 (203.1), Apple Script 2.7

---

### With PowerPoint

The code below worked. It successfully saved `test.pdf` under `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/Data/Documents`.

```
set outpath to "Documents/test.pdf"

tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    save active presentation in outpath as save as PDF
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outpath` is invalid anyway and it must be an HFS path

```
set outpath to (path to documents folder as text) & "test.pdf"

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    set activeDoc to active document
    save as activeDoc file name outpath file format format PDF
end tell
```

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you!! I thought something was wrong with "save as" command, but my path was wrong.